# How to find sqlite3 database corrupted?

Tags: c, linux, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 database for internal data storage. I will open the database at the beginning of the application, only database will close at the end of the application. In middle of the operation if database corrupted how will i know my db corrupted.

During my application running, i have manually corrupted the .db file and checked the response, i got **SQLITE_READONLY** error.

But once i closed and again opened the database, then executed one query this time i got correct **SQLITE_CORRUPT** error.

So can any one help me , how to find the database corruption without closing and again opening the database..???

i am using c language for coding.

Comment: Read "[How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)". Try to prevent corruption. You can not expect from SQLite, that the library can reliably detect any kind of disk corruption.

Comment: Then how i will know what exactly happened in database.

Answer (score 2):

To try to find corruption, you could run [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) or [PRAGMA quick_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_quick_check). However, corrupted data might look like real data, so there is no guaranteee that corruption can be found.

If at all possible, you should use working hardware/software to prevent corruption happening in the first place.

Comment: I have tried  PRAGMA integrity_check and PRAGMA quick_check but i am getting response OK.